# Pre load huge numpy arrays in parallel when train or predict with tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, asynchronous, parallel-processing, tensorflow

First of all I'm using numpy arrays as initial data and I'm not going to change that.

So each file contains separated example(let's say it's bigger than 100Mb). I do my logic on it in batches(kind of sliding windows). Then I need to save result for that sample.

I've noticed that reading that file from disk adds noticeable delay(especially when you predict).

My idea is to load next file in parallel with the training/prediction process so that delay becomes negligible. 
Probably I should use FIFOQueue, but can't put it together.

Schematically the whole pipeline can be represented as

Read numpy array => Split it in chunks => Process each chunk(batch) => Store that slice in a new numpy array => Save predicted result for the whole file

Comment: I would recommend official queues tutorial and maybe slides from my queues talk -- https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/tree/master/queues_talk

Comment: thanks, I'll check. Until that I've implemented that with thread pool and read/save ahead trick.